# "Kernel Restarting" constantly appearing on Jupyter Notebook in GCP

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, jupyter-notebook, google-cloud-dataproc

working with Hadoop Dataproc-Clusters on the google cloud platform I constantly get the message "Kernel restarting, Kernel (...) appears to have died. It will start automatically", and lose all my calculations in the jupyter notebook. I dont really see any pattern behind those errors, heavy calculations (pandas dataframes with >10M rows) are a the only driver I could identify. Cluster is set up with these configurations:

> gcloud dataproc clusters create cluster-v1 
> --region europe-west1 
> --zone europe-west1-b 
> --subnet datascience 
> --no-address 
> --scopes 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform' 
> --enable-component-gateway 
> --optional-components ANACONDA,JUPYTER 
> --bucket xxx-datascience 
> --image-version 1.5-debian10 
> --num-workers 3 
> --worker-machine-type c2-standard-16 
> --worker-boot-disk-size 500 
> --master-machine-type c2-standard-16 
> --master-boot-disk-size 500 
> --gce-pd-kms-key XXX 
> --project ssc

Any idea what triggers this error?

Comment: Some information may exist in the logs. Could you grab Jupyter logs or other relevant ones from the cluster and share some suspicious information if you find it?